# Vb.net WebClient.DownloadFileAsync wont work on xp and 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

hi i made a update function in vb.net that gives my users a notice when a new update is ready to be downloaded

so it all works on win 8 and 7 but when i try to run it on xp and 8.1 it just gives the download completed but dont downloads any file :s

here is my Code :

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form5
    Private Sub LogInButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LogInButton1.Click
        Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient
        AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, AddressOf client_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler client.DownloadFileCompleted, AddressOf client_DownloadCompleted
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("FILE the download"), "C:\users\" & System.Environment.UserName & _
                                 "\AppData\Local\Software_update.exe")
        LogInButton1.Text = "Download in Progress"
        LogInButton1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub client_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
        Dim bytesIn As Double = Double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString())
        Dim totalBytes As Double = Double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString())
        Dim percentage As Double = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100

        LogInProgressBar1.Value = Int32.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString())
    End Sub

    Private Sub client_DownloadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Download Complete please restart the app ")
        LogInButton1.Text = "Download Complete"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form5_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        Form1.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note i dint tested this yet on Vista

Comment: Almost certainly an exception is being thrown.  That exception is provided to you via the `e.Error` property in the `DownloadCompleted` event handler.  Look at it and it will tell you what went wrong.  You really should know this already because you should have read the documentation for `WebClient` class and the members you're using.

Answer (score 0):

i have already fix the problem the problem was that the appdata folder is different for each os :D

i used this to fix it

```
Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)


client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("FILE_URL"), appData & "\Software_update.exe")
```